# Detect if raster is within, without, or intersecting a SpatialPolygons object

Tags: r, r-sp, r-raster

I have many rasters for which I'd like to check if they are contain fully within a spatial polygon, fully without the spatial polygon, or intersecting with the spatial polygon (this could mean the polygon is fully within the raster, or the polygon and raster overlap).  I'm doing this check to save me from time intensive masking when possible.

Here is an example:

```
                                      # create 3 example rasters
r <- raster()
r[] <- rnorm(n = ncell(r))
e1 <- extent(c(45,55,45,50))
r1 <- crop(r,e1)
e2 <- extent(c(20,25,25,30))
r2 <- crop(r,e2)
e3 <- extent(c(38,55,57,65))
r3 <- crop(r,e3)


                                        #create SpatialPolygons

x <- c(40,60)
y <- c(40,60)
m <- expand.grid(x,y)
m <- m[c(1,2,4,3),]
p1 <- Polygon(m)
p1 <- Polygons(list(p1),1)

x <- c(10,15)
y <- c(10,15)
m <- expand.grid(x,y)
m <- m[c(1,2,4,3),]
p2 <- Polygon(m)
p2 <- Polygons(list(p2),2)

x <- c(30,45)
y <- c(70,80)
m <- expand.grid(x,y)
m <- m[c(1,2,4,3),]
p3 <- Polygon(m)
p3 <- Polygons(list(p3),3)


poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(p1,p2,p3))
```

plotting these:

[image: three rasters and three polygons]

I will read in each raster separately and check if it is within, without, or intersecting the SpatialPolygons.

What do you think will be the most efficient way to do this in R?  I have thousands of 4mb rasters that I'm planning to mask in parallel and would like this check to speed things up a bit.

Note, there's also this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34535/detect-whether-there-is-a-spatial-polygon-in-a-spatial-extent

However, I don't think it gives the detail I'm looking for.  For example, all of the rasters are within the *extent* of the spatial polygons, but not all are within the spatial polygons.

Functions like those in rgeos (gIntersects, gContains), would probably be handy.  I'm not sure if these are most efficient, or how I should convert raster (or it's extent), to an sp object.

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `gRelate` for this. It returns a [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) code that describes the relationships between interior, boundary and exterior components of the two geometries.

```
library(rgeos)
x <- sapply(rlist, function(x) 
  gsub('[^F]', 'T', gRelate(as(extent(x), 'SpatialPolygons'), poly)))
```

You could then compare the strings to relationships of interest. For example we might define `within`, `disjoint`, and `overlaps` as follows (but note that other some intersections are optional for given relationships - "within" is [defined by GEOS](http://geos.refractions.net/ro/doxygen_docs/html/classgeos_1_1geom_1_1Geometry.html) as `T*F**F***`, "disjoint" as `FF*FF****`, and "overlaps" as `T*T***T**`):

```
pat <- c(TFFTFFTTT='within', FFTFFTTTT='disjoint', TTTTTTTTT='overlaps')
pat[x]

##  TFFTFFTTT  FFTFFTTTT  TTTTTTTTT 
##   "within" "disjoint"  "overlaps"
```

It seems marginally faster than [the `gContainsProperly`/`gIntersects` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34686946/489704), but @Tedward's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34686946/489704) is more comprehensible, and more consistent with GEOS definitions (though the power to create specific relationship definitions might be desirable).

---

The elements of the DE-9IM strings represent, in order:

1. Does the interior of geometry A intersect the interior of geometry B?
2. Does the boundary of A intersect the interior of B?
3. Does the exterior of A intersect the interior of B?
4. Does the interior of geometry A intersect the boundary of geometry B?
5. Does the boundary of A intersect the boundary of B?
6. Does the exterior of A intersect the boundary of B?
7. Does the interior of geometry A intersect the exterior of geometry B?
8. Does the boundary of A intersect the exterior of B?
9. Does the exterior of A intersect the exterior of B?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of gRelate.  The flexibility is very useful and good to know about.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did to solve the problem:

```
library(rgeos)
rlist <- list(r1,r2,r3)

lapply(rlist, function(raster) {
  ei <- as(extent(raster), "SpatialPolygons")
  if (gContainsProperly(poly, ei)) {
    print ("fully within")
  } else if (gIntersects(poly, ei)) {
    print ("intersects")
  } else {
    print ("fully without")
  }
})
```

Please let me know if you know of a more efficient solution.

Comment: You will shave a little bit of time off by removing the `print` calls and the `proj4string` assignment.

Comment: Thanks, the print calls are just place holders.  I'm going to call some other functions.  Good call on the proj4string assignment.

Comment: (What I meant was you can just have, e.g., `'fully within'`, rather than `print('fully within')`, but if they're just placeholders don't worry about it)

Comment: gotcha, that's nice to know.  Thanks much!